# php deleting a table row

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a booking system for uni and have encountered an issue i need help with.

```
<?php
        $title = 'Room Booking';
        require_once 'header.php';
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `room1booking` ORDER BY date, start, id";

        if ($result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query)) {
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                    echo '<li>
                            ' . $row['name'] . '
                            ' . $row['date'] . '
                            ' . $row['start'] . '
                        <form action="confirmBooking.php?tid=' . $row['id'] . '" method="post">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit"><a href="confirmBooking.php?tid=' . $row['id'] . '">Confirm</a></button>
                            </form>
                            <form action="denyBooking.php?tid=' . $row['id'] . '" method="post">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit"><a href="denyBooking.php?tid=' . $row['id'] . '">Deny</a></button>
                         </form>
                         </li>
                         ';

                }

            } else {
                echo '<li>There are no results</li>';
            }

            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }


        mysqli_close($db_server);
    ?>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

This code is for the selecting of which row in the table that you want to delete

```
<?php
$title = 'Delete The Booking';
    require_once 'header.php';

    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

        $tid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, trim($_GET['tid']));

        if(!empty($tid)){

            $query = "DELETE FROM room1booking WHERE id = '$tid'";

            mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

            echo '<p>You have successfully deleted the booking.</p>';

    }
    } else {
        echo '<p>There is a problem with the system.</p>';

}


?>
```

And this is the code to delete the row

Any suggestions on where i am going wrong as the row won't delete

Comment: You are going wrong in not implementing any error checking whatsoever. So go read up on how to properly do that with MySQLi.

Comment: but @CBroe is there anything you can spot in this code that would not allow it to work?

Comment: You are using post in your form but are call the super global get in the delete code. Change these to post and try again

Comment: hi adam, i have modified the code, but alas, no luck. U have tried also what @gavgrif answered with, but also, no luck

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are passing the tid as a GET variable in the query string but the method of the form is POST. Note that both the confirmBooking and denyBooking forms have the same problem

```
<form action="denyBooking.php?tid=' . $row['id'] . '" method="post">
```

should be

```
 <form action="denyBooking.php?tid=' . $row['id'] . '" method="get">
```

Comment: thanks,that is right, as that line is for the confirming of the booking, i am looking at the deleting of one

Answer (score 0):

You have a combination of problems that would cause your record to not delete in the database:

1. Buttons don't send values in POST.  You need to add the id to a
   hidden input and retrieve the value in POST.
2. You've also mixed GET and POST.  Your form method is POST, but
   you're attempting to retrieve the variable from GET.  Since the
   action here is a delete, it's better to use POST (otherwise you need
   to account for users being able to delete any record by changing an
   url parameter).

**Solution:**

Create a hidden field and assign it's value using $row['id']

```
<input type="hidden" name="rowId" value="' . $row['id'] . '">
```

And the id will be in `$_POST['rowId']`

**Other notes:**

1. you should use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to verify 'rowId' exists in $_POST
   before you access it
2. if rowId should always be an integer, you should get the integer
   value of the string varaible using [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) before using it in
   your SQL query.
3. you should use [prepared statements with parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in
   your query.

Comment: HI devlin, thanks for the response, i have made the changes you have suggested, and in my site, i have made the page output <p> there is an error in the system </p>, if it doesn't work, and this is persistant after making the changes, any thoughts?

Comment: @MuzzaMurray - `echo $query` on the line after you assign a value to that variable.  Verify your query is correct.  Or, echo $query instead of the 'there is a problem' error message.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: query in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/elm/php/denyBooking.php on line 19 

this is the response i get for some reason

Comment: @MuzzaMurray - it's telling you that you have an undefined variable on line 19.  what's on line 19?

Comment: i had echo $query on line 19

Comment: @MuzzaMurray - echo $query instead of echoing `There is a problem with the system`.  This means you'll need to define query just after `require_once 'header.php';`  The next line should be:  `$query = "";`